# expo SMS.sendSMSAsync inside a loop pops sms modal and immediately closing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to send a text message using [`expo-sms`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sms/#smssendsmsasyncaddresses-message), the problem is when the sms modal is open to send the message - it immediately closing and the result of `SMS.sendSMSAsync` is `cancelled`.

my code is this:

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSend(contacts, text)}>{...}</TouchableOpacity>

async function handleSend(contacts, text) {
  try {
    const numbersArr = contacts.map(c => c.number)
    while (numbersArr.length > 0) {
      const number = numbersArr.pop()
      const { result } = await SMS.sendSMSAsync(number, text)
      // 'result' here is 'canceled' for each number
    }
    showMessagesSuccessfullySentMessage()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    showSmsSendingProblemError()
  }
}
```

SMS sending is available, of course, I do the check in advanced using `useEffect` when the component is mounted:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    ;(async function() {
      const isAvailable = await SMS.isAvailableAsync()
      setIsSmsAllowed(isAvailable)
    })()
  }, [])
```

**what am I doing wrong? what did I miss?**

Moreover, when I write a brand new app from scratch with the following code, everything works just perfect:

```js
const numbersArr = ['1234', '12345', '123456', '1234567'] // dummy numbers here

export default function App() {
  async function handleSend () {
    const isAvailable = await SMS.isAvailableAsync()
    if (isAvailable) {
      while (numbersArr.length > 0) {
        const n = numbersArr.pop()
        const result = await SMS.sendSMSAsync(n, 'My sample HelloWorld message')
        console.log('results', result)
      }
    } else {
      // misfortune... there's no SMS available on this device
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Button title="Send" onPress={handleSend}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

  some technical data and versions:
- tested on iPhone 11 Pro
- "expo": "~36.0.0"
- "expo-sms": "~8.0.0"

Comment: did you use expo install to add the expo-sms package?

Comment: @Phobos I actually re-installed the repo using `yarn`. do you think I shall run `expo install`?

Comment: Using expo install will ensure that you are running a version of expo-sms that is compatible with your current expo version.

Comment: but behind the scene it runs `yarn install` right?
Anyway - I get the same experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that my selected dummy contacts was accidentally created with the wrong phone number field, eventually resulted with `number=undefined` being called on `SMS.sendSMSAsync(undefined, 'My sample HelloWorld message')`
Obviously I created those dummy contacts to avoid testing the app on my real contacts...
(sorry for bothering the network)

[Opened an issue to `expo`](https://forums.expo.io/t/sms-sendsmsasync-should-warn-or-throw-for-passing-invalid-parameters/43061?u=zivl) to discuss the option to throw error or at least a warning in dev stage to warn for `undefined`/`null` value being passed to `SMS.sendSMSAsync`

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any known issues with Expo SMS at the moment. I wrote a small example Snack, you [can see it here](https://snack.expo.io/@bycedric/expo-sms-example). I've tested the dialog on both Android and iOS.

If you think this is an issue with Expo, please open an issue at expo/expo.

Comment: I don't think something is wrong with Expo, its not my first time using `expo-sms` so I'm pretty much familiar with the API. I've edited the code snippets above, I'm sending multiple text messages in a loop, maybe that'll help